# Why is node.js not running my Javascript code in VS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
PS C:\Main\Coding\JavaScript\Project Euler> node "c:\Main\Coding\JavaScript\Project Euler\Problem_4.js"


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 00000070F5DBE890
 1: 00007FF6245830AF v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+112511
 2: 00007FF6244A023F v8::CFunctionInfo::HasOptions+7055
 3: 00007FF625176392 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF624CFFCF5 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF624BC03B2 v8::Message::GetIsolate+16706
 6: 00007FF624A34711 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+26849
 7: 00007FF624ED2541 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
 8: 0000019E45FC857D


const palindromes = [];
const checkIfPalindromic = (number) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(number.length); i++) {
        if (number[i] === number[number.length - 1 - i]) {
            continue;
        }   else {
            return;
        }
    }
palindromes.push(number);
};

const createNumbers = (digits) => {
    for (let i = 10^(digits-1); i < 10^(digits); i++) {
        for (let j = 10^(digits-1); j < 10^(digits); j++) {
            checkIfPalindromic(i*j);
    }
}
console.log(palindromes);
};

createNumbers(2)
```

This is the error I'm getting with node v16.13.1, and the code I'm trying to run.

I can run really basic code like console.log("Hello") but not more complicated stuff. I'm using visual studio code.

Comment: this typically happens when the code you are running was written using an older version of Node.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't running? this can happens because of a mistake in it or that you wrote the code in a different Node version

Comment: I've posted it above. How can I tell which node version I should be using?

Comment: Your program is allocating ~2GB of memory which makes Node.js crash with `FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: On a side note: Do you mean `Math.pow(10, digits-1)` or `10**(digits-1)` instead of `10^(digits-1)`?

Comment: Yes, I do, thanks you.